# Wrapping text with css

Tags: css, word-wrap, firefox2

I have the following html:

```
<label class="description">Label Text</label><input type="password" />
```

And the css styles are:

```
fieldset span.formrow label.description {
    width: 150px;
    display: -moz-inline-box;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

My problem is that in Firefox 2 if the text goes over the 150px limit, then the line does not break. Instead the text is displayed behind the input text field.

Any chance that the behavior can be altered?

Comment: @Manni: how did you enable the coloring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
fieldset span.formrow label.description { 
  width: 150px; 
  float:left;
  clear:left; 
}
```

Try this!

Andrew

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
fieldset span.formrow label.description { width: 150px; display: block; float: left; }
```

Comment: you don't need display: block (float left forces that).

Comment: Hmm, so it does. Can't recall why I started adding that. Thanks!